# Multi-statement SQL transaction failing at null parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I have a multi-statement SQL query that takes place within a SqlTransaction as follows:

```
string sName = "";
string sNumber = "";
string sFirstName = "";

string sqlQuery1 = @"INSERT INTO myTable(Name, Number) VALUES (@_Name, @_Number)";
string sqlQuery2 = @"INSERT INTO myOtherTable( ID, FirstName) VALUES ( @_ID, @_First )";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConn(***);
conn.Open();
SqlTransaction transaction;

SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery1, conn, transaction);
SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery2, conn, transaction);

command1.Parameters.Add("@_Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = sName;
command1.Parameters.Add("@_Number", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = sNumber;

int? returnedID = (int?)command1.ExecuteScalar();

command2.Parameters.Add("@_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (int)returnedID;  <--- Error
command2.Parameters.Add("@_First", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = sFirstName;

command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

transaction.Commit();
```

At the line I marked as an error, I get an error during execution about "The parameterized query expects the parameter @_ID which was not supplied.

Now, assuming I have no typos while simplifying my code to this example, why am I receiving a null value in returnedID for a properly executed statement? When I just run the statement on its own in a query, I get no errors and it returns successful. Why null when running it in this transaction?  Thanks!

Edit: I purposely left off a try{} catch from this as it wasn't relevant to the question I had. Otherwise, I just forgot about the IDENTITY_SCOPE() that I needed in the Insert query since there would otherwise be no return value.

Comment: You are using a SQLTransaction object I would suggest wrapping the code in a try{}catch and in the exception code you will need a transaction.RollBack(); if that transaction fails..for starters..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). Your statement is an insert, it does not return any result set.

The easiest way to fix your example is to run all queries in one command and use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the inserted id.

```
string sqlQuery =
    @"INSERT INTO myTable(Name, Number) VALUES (@_Name, @_Number);
      INSERT INTO myOtherTable( ID, FirstName) VALUES ( SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @_First )";
```

Comment: @@IDENTITY should not be used, use scope_identity()  instead it is better.

Comment: @paritosh, you're right, @@IDENTITY can retrieve an id inserted in a different scope, I'll fix my answer. Thanks

Comment: Of course, I forgot all about adding Scope_Identity() to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since `insert` statements don't return a value, `ExecuteScalar()` can't return the identity as you want.  You can combine the `insert` with a `select scope_identity()` as in the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-5) on the `ExecuteScalar()` documentation to get the functionality I think you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to assume that `INSERT INTO myTable(Name, Number) VALUES (@_Name, @_Number)` is going to return the ID of the inserted row; why would you think that?  The assumption is incorrect, which is why you're getting a null value back from ExecuteScalar.

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) returns null if the command's result set is empty, and the result set of an [INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) statement is in fact empty, unless you include an [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.